# How to vary alignment in document?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I wanted to **left align** my document in such a way that some pages...e.g. **Abstract** to remain justified, but the rest of the document left aligned. Anyway to do that?

Comment: As you have asked 9 question so far and 7 of them have got at least one answer, it would be nice if you started to upvote helpful answers and to accept the "best" (in your opinion) answer to each question.

Comment: @ lockstep: Oh yes...thanks very much for the reminder! A lot of times I try to do that but didn't know that the icons are on the left:-( I will now and henceforth! Cheers

Comment: It's also allowed to make up leeway with regard to former questions. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\raggedright
\lipsum[2]

\justifying
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of using `\raggedright` it might be better for hyphenation to use `\RaggedRight` (which is defined in `ragged2e`).

Answer (score 4):

As Harrold Cavendish mentioned it can be done with the `ragged2e` package. In the following example the whole document is set to raggedright by using the `document` option and the abstract is kept justified by placed inside a `justifying` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  \begin{justify}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{justify}
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The following is said of the `document` option of `ragged2e` in the manual:

> This options sets the complete
>   document ragged-right by executing a
>   `\RaggedRight` at `\begin{document}`
>   and the `raggedrightboxes` and the
>   `footnotes` options.

Comment: `\justifying` is the command; the environment that uses it is named `justify`.

Comment: I am sorry for making it look like I am too lazy to post an answer and then posting it before you. I thought I did not have time but then decided to add the answer anyway.

Comment: @BrettHarry What happens when you try it? If you get an error please paste it here.

Comment: @Harrold, @lockstep,@ NN: Thanks...it looks great with the sample you showed...but on my document it didnt. I did it as `documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{Thesis}`,`\usepackage{ragged2e}`,`\begin{document}`,`\raggedright`,`\input{,/Chapters/Chapter1}`,`\end{document}`           The are two errors: 1) `! LaTeX Error: There is no line to end.` 2) `pdtLaTeX warning: _/usr/texbin/pdflatex: pop empty colorpage stack 0`. These errors occur only when I add the `\raggedright` under `\begin{document}`. Did I mess up something? I have a huge thesis and wanted to issue the command once. Cheers

Comment: @BrettHarry Actually, I think you should make a new question for this problem.

Comment: @BrettHarry You seem to have a quite old TeX distribution, judging from the `pop empty colorpage stack 0` message. Moreove it's impossible to check if you don't give an address where to find the `Thesis` class. On the other hand, the `There is no line to end` is usually related to two ``\\`` commands in a row, which is a "no no".

Comment: @egreg: Thanks....the `Thesis class` is : `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]\ProvidesClass{Thesis}[2007/22/02 v1.0 LaTeX document class]'. Is there a newer version to replace it? I have an updated MacTex though.

Comment: @BrettHarry: It's not a standard class, nor it is in CTAN. There's no way we can help if you don't say where it can be found.

Comment: @egred : Thank you so much! You have already helped! I just changed the class date from `[1996/12/01]` to `[1999/12/01]` and it worked! The thesis class is in my `Thesis.cls` file.